# When I try to initialize a class to call one of its method, an error comes up, how to resolve this?

Tags: java, android, constructor, android-arrayadapter

I'm making an android app that requires a custom array adapter. In this class which extends array adapter consists of media player initialization. I created another method under this class to release the media player as soon as the activity with which the word adapter is associated stops. When I created the stop method in the activity and tried to intialize the Custom Array Adapter class  an error comes up saying that "Constructor cannot be applied to ()",Alternatively when I tried WordAdapter w=null and called the method I wanted to no error came but During runtime the application force closed!
Here's the activity code:

```
public class ColorsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

    // Create a list of words
    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    words.add(new Word("red", "weṭeṭṭi",R.drawable.color_red,R.raw.color_red));
    words.add(new Word("mustard yellow", "chiwiiṭә",R.drawable.color_mustard_yellow,R.raw.color_mustard_yellow));
    words.add(new Word("dusty yellow", "ṭopiisә",R.drawable.color_dusty_yellow,R.raw.color_dusty_yellow));
    words.add(new Word("green", "chokokki",R.drawable.color_green,R.raw.color_green));
    words.add(new Word("brown", "ṭakaakki",R.drawable.color_brown,R.raw.color_brown));
    words.add(new Word("gray", "ṭopoppi",R.drawable.color_gray,R.raw.color_gray));
    words.add(new Word("black", "kululli",R.drawable.color_black,R.raw.color_black));
    words.add(new Word("white", "kelelli",R.drawable.color_white,R.raw.color_white));

    // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
    // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
    WordAdapter adapter = new WordAdapter(this, words,R.color.category_colors);

    // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
    // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
    // word_list.xml layout file.
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
    // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    WordAdapter w= new WordAdapter();
    w.terminate();
    super.onStop();


    // TODO: Implement this method

}

}
```

And the Custom adapter code :

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {
    int b;
    MediaPlayer mp;


    /**
     * Create a new {@link WordAdapter} object.
     *
     * @param context is the current context (i.e. Activity) that the adapter is being created in.
     * @param words is the list of {@link Word}s to be displayed.
     */
    private int mbgcolor;
    public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int BgColor)
    {
        super(context, 0, words);
        mbgcolor = BgColor;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null)
        {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID miwok_text_view.
        TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
        // Get the Miwok translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
        // the Miwok TextView.
        miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslation());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID default_text_view.
        TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
        // Get the default translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
        // the default TextView.
        defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslation());
        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID list_item_icon

        if (currentWord.hasImage())
        {
            ImageView iconView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_image_view);
            // Get the image resource ID from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set the image to iconView
            iconView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());
            iconView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            ImageView iconView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_image_view);
            iconView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        View text_container=listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
        int bgc=ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mbgcolor);
        text_container.setBackgroundColor(bgc);
        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews) so that it can be shown in
        // the ListView.
        int song= currentWord.getSongResourceId();
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(getContext(),song);
         text_container.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View v)
             {
                mp.start(); 

             }
         });

        return listItemView;

    }
    public void terminate()
    {
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I may have overlooked it (sooo much code .... ), but you don't seem to have a no-argument constructor for your WordAdapter. So `new WordAdapter()` should fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All, this has nothing to do with `Android`, It's a general programming question!

---

your `class(WordAdapter)`'s constructor is defined like this:

```
public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int BgColor)
{
    super(context, 0, words);
    mbgcolor = BgColor;
}
```

The problem is:

**1**- you are calling it wrong! `WordAdapter w= new WordAdapter();`

you are calling an empty constructor which does not exists in your class! so of course this will show you error

**2**- Even if this constructor (the empty one) exists, you code is still wrong because in `onStop` you are calling `terminate()` on a new object of the class other than the one you used in `onCreate` (which you have named it `adapter`).

So as solution for this make the `adapter` object a global variable for all of your `Activity`'s methods like that:

```
private WordAdapter adapter;
```

and **use it** inside `onCreate` and Also inside `onStop`

Comment: @MahaDev You're welcome :) Plz for this answer or any other answer, if it helped you then accept it as correct answer for other people who may come across your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating a new adapter every time in the onStop instead of using the existing one.

```
ColorsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WordAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_list);

    // Create a list of words
    ArrayList<Word> words = new ArrayList<Word>();
    words.add(new Word("red", "weṭeṭṭi",R.drawable.color_red,R.raw.color_red));
    words.add(new Word("mustard yellow", "chiwiiṭә",R.drawable.color_mustard_yellow,R.raw.color_mustard_yellow));
    words.add(new Word("dusty yellow", "ṭopiisә",R.drawable.color_dusty_yellow,R.raw.color_dusty_yellow));
    words.add(new Word("green", "chokokki",R.drawable.color_green,R.raw.color_green));
    words.add(new Word("brown", "ṭakaakki",R.drawable.color_brown,R.raw.color_brown));
    words.add(new Word("gray", "ṭopoppi",R.drawable.color_gray,R.raw.color_gray));
    words.add(new Word("black", "kululli",R.drawable.color_black,R.raw.color_black));
    words.add(new Word("white", "kelelli",R.drawable.color_white,R.raw.color_white));

    // Create an {@link WordAdapter}, whose data source is a list of {@link Word}s. The
    // adapter knows how to create list items for each item in the list.
    mAdapter = new WordAdapter(this, words,R.color.category_colors);

    // Find the {@link ListView} object in the view hierarchy of the {@link Activity}.
    // There should be a {@link ListView} with the view ID called list, which is declared in the
    // word_list.xml layout file.
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Make the {@link ListView} use the {@link WordAdapter} we created above, so that the
    // {@link ListView} will display list items for each {@link Word} in the list.
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    mAdapter.terminate();
    super.onStop();


    // TODO: Implement this method

}

}
```